# Ajuda com formulário dentro de WHILE

Tags: while

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar valores individuais de cada botão de like, pois quando curto uma vez um comentário ele acaba recebendo a quantia dos outros... Exemplo; Se tem 2 comentários ele recebe 2Likes, se 3 recebe 3 e assim sucessivamente...

Segue o código

```
<?php
                          $selecionaLike = "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE idcomentario = '$idComentarioLinha'";
                          $execSelecionaLike = mysqli_query($conexaoBanco, $selecionaLike);
                          $contaLike = mysqli_num_rows($execSelecionaLike);
                          $selecionaDeslike = "SELECT * FROM deslike WHERE idcomentario = '$idComentarioLinha'";
                          $execSelecionaDeslike = mysqli_query($conexaoBanco, $selecionaDeslike);
                          $contaDeslike = mysqli_num_rows($execSelecionaDeslike);
                        ?>                            

                        <div id="like" style="padding-right: 10px;">
                        <form method="POST" action="" style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;">
                          <button type="submit" name="like" value="<?php echo($idComentarioLinha);?>" style="background-color: #44bd32;padding: 3px;border-radius: 5px;color: #fff;margin-right: 5px;"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> <?php echo "$contaLike";?></button>
                          <button type="submit" name="deslike" value="<?php echo($idComentarioLinha);?>" style="background-color: #eb2f06;padding: 3px;border-radius: 5px;color: #fff;margin-right: 5px;"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i> <?php echo "$contaDeslike";?></button>                       
                        </form>                      

                          <?php
                          if(isset($_POST['like'])){
                            $i++;
                            $like = $_POST['like'];
                            echo "$like";
                            var_dump($like);
                            $likes = "INSERT INTO likes (idcomentario) VALUES ('$like')";
                            $execlikes = mysqli_query($conexaoBanco, $likes);
                          }
                          if(isset($_POST['deslike'])){
                            $deslike = $_POST['deslike'];
                            $deslikes = "INSERT INTO deslike (idcomentario) VALUES ('$deslike')";
                            $exedeslikes = mysqli_query($conexaoBanco,$deslikes);
                          }
                          ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Já resolvi, apenas tirei essa parte de dentro do while...

```
<?php
                      if(isset($_POST['like'])){
                        $i++;
                        $like = $_POST['like'];
                        echo "$like";
                        var_dump($like);
                        $likes = "INSERT INTO likes (idcomentario) VALUES ('$like')";
                        $execlikes = mysqli_query($conexaoBanco, $likes);
                      }
                      if(isset($_POST['deslike'])){
                        $deslike = $_POST['deslike'];
                        $deslikes = "INSERT INTO deslike (idcomentario) VALUES ('$deslike')";
                        $exedeslikes = mysqli_query($conexaoBanco,$deslikes);
                      }
                      ?>
```